# How to prevent NServiceBus from rolling back the transaction or parts of it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, msmq, nservicebus

We have a handler that performs as supposed to when it's received a message. There are several steps in the process and each consecutive one creates its own, new context, as shown below.

```
public void Handle(SomeMessage message)
{
  ...
  try
  {
    ...
    using(DataContext context = new DataContext()) { ... }
    ...
    using(DataContext context = new DataContext()) { ... }
    ...
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  { 
    ...
    using(DataContext context = new DataContext()) { ... }
    ...
  }
}
```

However, on occasion, an exception is thrown and caught in it. The current transaction is rolled back (and since it's not implemented by me explicitly, I'm assuming, without being utterly certain, that it's done by the NServiceBus itself because all the results written to the DB disappear, including those in the *catch* statement).

At the moment, I'm resolving it by writing to a file when something terrible happens but I'd love to have that stored in the DB as well.

So, ultimately, I'd like to prevent that the last operation, the one in *catch* statement, is rolled back. Can one do that and if so how?

Comment: you said like as the code you posted is not yours?

Comment: @Hopeless Not sure what you mean. The code isn't mine legally because it belongs to the company I'm working for. But it's mine in the sense that I've written it. (Well, the team is bigger than just me, of course, but this particular part is mostly me.) Am I misunderstanding your question, perhaps? I didn't set up the bus (and the guy who did is long gone).

Comment: do you mean `the last operation` is what done in `using(DataContext context = new DataContext()) { ... }` (inside catch) or ***everything*** inside catch? I mean I don't understand what you actually want to prevent (the last sentence).

Comment: @Hopeless Now I get you. I want the rollback to be carried out on **everything** except the part that I'm doing in the *catch* statement. So, every context's change must be rolled back. Except the one where I log the error to the DB, which is done when it's been caught. There's only one *using* in there so, to your question - yes, everything in the *catch* statement needs to be committed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd really like to know the bigger issue, what are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to log something to the database when an error occurs? If it's technical related, the messages should start appearing in the error queue, you should fix the error and have NServiceBus retry the messages. When it's business related, you should have an alternate route to handle the specific business requirement. For example you're out of stock of a specific item, then it might be better to email the buyer to wait for their item or tell them they can get their money back. And inform sales that someone bought an item out of stock, or something like it.

NServiceBus does rollback all transactions, but this is a `TransactionScope` related issue. Start a new `TransactionScope` and tell it to be a new root transaction.

```
using(TransactionScope scope1 = new TransactionScope()) 
//Default is Required 
{ 
     using(TransactionScope scope2 = new 
      TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required)) 
     {
     ...
     } 

     using(TransactionScope scope3 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)) 
     {
     ...
     } 

     using(TransactionScope scope4 = new 
        TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)) 
    {
     ...
    } 
}
```

The scope3 transaction is a transaction on its own. If you want, put this inside your catch scope.

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152(VS.90).aspx) explains it all.
But again, I'd rather have more information on what you're actually trying to achieve. And perhaps read up on [this article](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/).

Comment: You're making a number of interesting suggestions by your questions. You're barking up the right tree, stating the separation of errors due to technicals versus business logic. In our case, those are not directly applicable **but** a certain adaptation of these **is indeed**. Definitely +1 for that.